# Asp.net textbox validate event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Im new in asp.net. I want to know how to fire textbox validate event. Just like as windows app textbox validate event. I enter the Product no. in asp.net textbox and if this Product no. exist in database so this Product no. information retrieve from database.

Comment: You will have to set up an event to fire a jQuery function when the textbox loses focus.  In this function you can perform an AJAX call to check whatever you want and respond to the user.

Comment: You could also use the asp:textbox's [OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. This will fire any validation you place inside it each time a postback occurs where the textbox's contents differ from the previous post. Ensure you set `AutoPostback="true"`

Comment: Can you please give me the example.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use some jquery function.

Like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#<%=txtProduct.ClientID %>').blur(ShowAvailability);
});

function ShowAvailability() {    
    // your code 
}
```

Comment: @Sunny - What exactly you want to do ?? or better show some code so that we can help you more precisely...

Comment: @Sunny - Check my answer at your given link.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to add a search button. In code behind of the search button query your DB table  and then you can print result in a label. or display a jquery modal to user.